# C# BackgroundWorker and Streamwriter

Tags: c#, asynchronous, backgroundworker, streamwriter

I am having issue writing/Reading string into file with BackgroundWorker
But I don't know where is it hapenning.

When i click "start" on my app, i'm checking whether there's a first line or not in a file :

```
StreamWriter writeToCsv;
public string filename;
public bool canAcces = false;
public bool enteteExiste = false;

private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            filename = filename_box.Text;
            if (filename_valid(filename) == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nom du fichier incorrect \n Seuls les caractères propre a Windows sont autorisés \n Le fichier doit se terminer par .csv");
            }


            //DEMARRAGE DE LA PROCEDURE
            boxLogs.Clear();
            if (filename_valid(filename))
            {
                try
                {
                    verifieEntete();
                    //INSERTION DE L'ENTETE DU FICHIER CSV
                    writeToCsv = new StreamWriter(boxFilePath.Text + "\\" + filename, true);
                    canAcces = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

This task is completed synchronous. It's the first thing that the program do.
The function "verifieEntete()" is changing a boolean, "enteteExiste"

```
public void verifieEntete()
        {
             string absolutFilePath = boxFilePath.Text + '\\' + filename;
             if (!File.Exists(absolutFilePath))
             {
                 File.Create(absolutFilePath).Close();

             }
                String[] fileContent = File.ReadAllText(absolutFilePath).Split(',');
                for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.Length; i++)
                    if (fileContent[i].Contains("MAC;SERIAL;IP;MODELE;MODULE-EXT;NUM-COURT;SITE"))
                        enteteExiste = true;          
        }
```

Now, here comes the asynchronous part.
I did this :

```
    public void startParListe()
{
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    if (bw.IsBusy != true)
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

And in my bw_DoWork function, here are the first lines :

```
public void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    countPlages = listePlages.Items.Count;
        if (countPlages != 0 && boxFilePath.Text != "" && canAcces == true && filename_valid(filename))
        {
            tableauPlages = new string[countPlages, 2];
            if (enteteExiste == false)
            {
                writeToCsv.WriteLine("MAC;SERIAL;IP;MODELE;MODULE-EXT;NUM-COURT;SITE");
            }
        }
}
```

Here's the issue :
The program runs, create the file (if not exists) then should put a first line in it :

```
writeToCsv.WriteLine("MAC;SERIAL;IP;MODELE;MODULE-EXT;NUM-COURT;SITE");
```

But instead, the program create the file, but don't put anything in it. And even worst, the program does not end. As if it's looping on this WriteLine but never write it.

I have tons of other instructions after that, but i can see that none of its are executed.
What is wrong with the background worker and Streamwriter ?

Comment: In the debugger, put a break point in `bw_doWork` and check the state of everything is what you expect: with concurrent activity and *no locking* your state could easily be messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is better to close and dispose your `StreamWriter` when you're done with it:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(boxFilePath.Text + "\\" + filename, true))
{
    canAcces = true;
}
```

Reopen a new `StreamWriter` when you are writing the actual data.

```
if (enteteExiste == false)
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(boxFilePath.Text + "\\" + filename, true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("MAC;SERIAL;IP;MODELE;MODULE-EXT;NUM-COURT;SITE");
    }
}
```

If you don't dispose, a file handle will remain open, which can lead to hard to debug issues, especially in a multi-threading environment.

If performance is an issue with this approach, consider to write the data to a buffer and write that buffer to a file in longer intervals.

I think this will help.

Comment: So, in further code i have some other blocks where i'm writing using the "writeToCsv" var. Everytime before writing now with Writer i have to declare it with the "using" statement ?

Comment: Yes, unless you are really aware of what you're doing. The `StreamWriter` has a `IDisposable` interface, which is used to release unmanaged resources (like file handles). Not doing so might cause unexpected errors. The `using` statement calls this `Dispose()` function implicit. `IDisposable` interface is usually added to `Streams`, `DatabaseContexts`, `GDI/Graphics objects`, `Images` etc. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx for details.